# concurrency in innodb

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, innodb

i have a code like this

reserve.php

```
$r=mysql_query("select count(*) from ticket");
$rec=mysql_fetch_array($r);
if ($rec[0]==0)
{
insert into ticket values .....
}
```

i have 1 ticket only.
two users request reserve.php.

"a" user request reserve.php and available ticket is 0 . but before insert, for "b" user  available ticket is 0 yet. so two users reserve ticket.

table is Innodb.
how to prevent this? transaction , lock table or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these situations I usually just use an UPDATE statement and check how many records were affected (mysql_affected_rows) by the update.

```
 UPDATE tickets SET ticket_count=ticket_count-1 WHERE ticket_id=123 AND ticket_count>0
```

If someone else decremented the counter first, then no update occurs and you don't give the user a ticket. Autocommit should be enabled so the update is a self-contained "transaction".

Alternatively, you can change your SELECT to be SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: do it needs to use set tranaction before select for update and insert?

Comment: i think yes.  "Locks set by LOCK IN SHARE MODE and FOR UPDATE reads are released when the transaction is committed or rolled back".

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in a single transaction, without a roundtrip back to the application level - both `SELECT count() ....` and `INSERT INTO` being sent in a single command from PHP and embedded into a `TRANSACTION` with `EXCLUSIVE LOCK`

Comment: how to set EXCLUSIVE LOCK?. what if 2 users see transaction in same time?

Comment: As Brent indicated - the `EXCLUSIVE LOCK` is called `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in MySQL